# "Localhost refused to connect" using Microsoft Graph Toolkit on a deployed Microsoft Teams custom personal app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-toolkit, teams-toolkit

Error:

[image]

We’re using the Microsoft Graph Toolkit for login credentials in order to use the Microsoft Graph API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/overview

With version 2.1.0:

[image]

And we did the Azure AD App Registration following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/add-aad-app-registration

[image]

So, what I think we need, is to change the localhost URI to point to the deployed Teams app. Something like: `https://<teams-tenant>/<teams-app>/auth.html`. But I can’t figure it out.

[image]

What am I missing?

Precisions/Edits:

- When running Teams App **locally** using `npm start`, we can sign in user and get profile information. The MGT and Azure App are properly configured following Microsoft documentation (for local runs but not for deployments).

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Create Teams App using Microsoft Teams Toolkit Extension version 1.2.3 as "Personnal Tab" without SSO
2. Configure Microsoft Graph Toolkit version 2.1.0 following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab#add-the-microsoft-graph-toolkit
3. Make sure the Azure Active Directory App is created following this step: Add Microsoft Graph Toolkit following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab#add-the-microsoft-graph-toolkit
4. Test and run locally (Add Microsoft Graph Toolkit following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab#add-the-microsoft-graph-toolkit) - This should work
5. Upload appPackage.zip in Teams Admin Center (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/manage-apps?toc=%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fmicrosoftteams%2Fplatform%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#customize-an-app)
6. Install App in Teams and try to access it. As soon as it tries to load the app, we get the localhost error.

Comment: Looks like this is a teams app, Are you following along [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab) as well? You'll need to rout the auth with the teams provider [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab#initialize-in-javascript) otherwise, some more info on your configuration would help.

Comment: Local host URL cannot be added as tab in teams. It must be public available URL. So, You can create public URL using Ngrok/Azure relay or else publish app to azure.

Comment: @NicVogt Thank you for the pointers Nic. But we did follow the Microsoft documentation to setup MGT with a Microsoft Teams Tab. What I failed to mention (and I'll update the post) is that the configuration for the MGT and the Azure App are working. I'm able to sign in with a user when running npm start. It's when the app is deployed that I get the error. I need to change localhost to point to the Teams' public folder. And I can't find any Microsoft documentation on how to do that.

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru Yes exactly!! Ngrok and Azure are out of the question, they are too expensive. When generating a Teams App with the Microsoft Teams Toolkit, it creates that "public" facing folder/URL (see screenshot with index.html and favicon.ico). Do you know how to use it? How to reference to it?

Comment: If you are referring toolkit >2.0, index.html published as static website using azure storage account. So, you would require to use storage account specific URL. Here is the reference: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension,   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/visual-studio-code-overview

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru Sorry Subba. I just don't understand where you're going with this. I believe my understanding of authentication in Teams is lacking at this point. I can't even formulate a proper question.

Comment: @Jean-PierreToupin - Hello, Can you please share the repro steps?
The files under public folder can be accessed directly: {baseResouce}/fileName.xyz. 

But for the authentication we usually have route. Can you please check in App.js/App.tsx is there any route for auth.html? 
One last thing the doc you shared says: "_In the Redirect URI field, in the dropdown, select Single Page Application (SPA), and in the URL field, enter http://localhost:3000_"
You sure you are following steps correctly?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Hi. I added the repro steps in the original post, good idea, thank you. As for the {baseRessource}/fileName.xyz (or {baseUrl}), where should I put it. I tried in manifest.json and Azure AD App and it didn't work. We do have a route in our App.tsx, it's the generated one for our "/tab", should we add a route to the auth.html as well? Do you have a doc supporting that idea, how would it work? And lastly, the doc is confusing but we need "auth.html" in redirect URI: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab#creating-an-appclient-id

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting to see:
[image]

Okay, so basically if you want to test the app on Teams it should be running somewhere: You can run it locally by *"**npm start**"* or you deploy this on Azure or any app service.

You don't need to change *Redirect URI* of Azure AD registration until you are testing from local.

Please make sure you have your app using *"**npm start**"* and then try to access Teams tab.
It should work.

Thanks

Comment: Yes! This is what I expect to see. And yes, it works locally when I use "npm start". Now, can you deploy this app in Microsoft Teams Admin Center and let me know if you get the localhost error? Thanks

Comment: @Jean-PierreToupin - If you are planning to to deploy app in Microsoft Teams Admin Center and want to make it accessible to all. You need the public facing URL of the deployed app, it doesn't work with localhost. 

You can publish your app on Azure App Service. Thanks

Comment: It's okay, I think I found what I was looking for! The problem was with the MGT. If I remove it and exchange Teams access Token with an on-behlaf-of flow I'll still have access to Microsoft Graph API. Source: https://www.wictorwilen.se/blog/microsoft-teams-tabs-sso-and-microsoft-graph-the-on-behalf-of-blog-post/